# Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is working fine in SQL Server 2008 but when i try to run the same procedure in SQL server 2005 it throws this error stating

Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

following is my sp

```
USE dbEmployeeManagementSystem
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spInsertTaskAssignmentsample
(
@Username nvarchar(50),
@ProjectName nvarchar(50),
@ClientName nvarchar(50),
@Status nvarchar(50),
@StartDate nvarchar(50),
@EndDate nvarchar(50),
@ReportingManager nvarchar(50),
@Comments nvarchar(100)
 )
AS
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO tblTaskAssignment
(EID,ProjectName, ClientName, Status, StartDate, EndDate,ReportingManager,Comments) 
Values
((SELECT top 1 EID FROM tblLogin WHERE Username=@Username), @ProjectName, @ClientName, @Status, @StartDate, @EndDate,@ReportingManager,@Comments)
END
```

Please help me, is there any solution for this or sql 2005 doest support such kind of queries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `SELECT` *instead* of a `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO tblTaskAssignment
(EID,ProjectName, ClientName, Status, StartDate, EndDate,ReportingManager,Comments) 
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 EID FROM tblLogin WHERE Username=@Username), @ProjectName, @ClientName, @Status, @StartDate, @EndDate,@ReportingManager,@Comments
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2005 doesn't support this. It was introduced in 2008.

You can assign the result of the subquery to a variable instead and use that in the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Assigning to a variable seems overkill. Does 2005 not support `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is - It does but if the subquery returns `0` rows that is trickier. It should insert `NULL`.

Comment: The variable and the subquery will return `NULL` either way? `INSERT INTO ... SELECT (subquery), @v1, @v2`

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Ah see what you mean. I thought you meant `INSERT ... SELECT top 1 EID, @ProjectName, @ClientName FROM tblLogin WHERE Username=@Username`

Comment: Well I wouldn't say a variable is  overkill...It's just two ways of getting the job done. I wouldn't say that the differences are that big :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative 1:

You can put EID into a variable like this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spInsertTaskAssignmentsample
    (
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @ProjectName nvarchar(50),
    @ClientName nvarchar(50),
    @Status nvarchar(50),
    @StartDate nvarchar(50),
    @EndDate nvarchar(50),
    @ReportingManager nvarchar(50),
    @Comments nvarchar(100)
     )
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @EID INT;
    SET @EID = (SELECT top 1 EID FROM tblLogin WHERE Username=@Username);

    INSERT INTO tblTaskAssignment
    (EID,ProjectName, ClientName, Status, StartDate, EndDate,ReportingManager,Comments) 
    Values
    (@EID, @ProjectName, @ClientName, @Status, @StartDate, @EndDate,@ReportingManager,@Comments)
    END
```

If EID is not of integer type, you'll have to specify that type in the declare statement

Alternative 2:
Use a SELECT clause

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spInsertTaskAssignmentsample
    (
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @ProjectName nvarchar(50),
    @ClientName nvarchar(50),
    @Status nvarchar(50),
    @StartDate nvarchar(50),
    @EndDate nvarchar(50),
    @ReportingManager nvarchar(50),
    @Comments nvarchar(100)
     )
    AS
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tblTaskAssignment
    (EID,ProjectName, ClientName, Status, StartDate, EndDate,ReportingManager,Comments) 
    SELECT TOP 1 EID, @ProjectName, @ClientName, @Status, @StartDate, @EndDate,@ReportingManager,@Comments FROM tblLogin WHERE Username=@Username 
    END
```

Comment: Alternative 2 may fail if there is no user with `@Username` in the tblLogin table but that will only be a problem if the stored procedure is to expect that a "missing" `@username` may be input

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT` *instead* of a `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO tblTaskAssignment
(EID,ProjectName, ClientName, Status, StartDate, EndDate,
    ReportingManager,Comments) 
SELECT top 1 EID, @ProjectName, @ClientName, @Status, @StartDate, @EndDate,
    @ReportingManager,@Comments
FROM tblLogin WHERE Username=@Username
```

(Although note, as per the discussion between Martin Smith and ta.speot.is, this does assume that there will be at least one row in `tblLogin` that matches `@Username`)

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I was just adding that as a specific assumption - we don't know whether the OP needs to deal with that aspect or not (perhaps the original query falls over even on 2008 in such a circumstance, because `EID` isn't nullable)

Comment: Or write the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` in a way that doesn't make the assumption.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - the point is, *you're* assuming that `NULL` is a valid value here, and a desirable result.

Comment: The OP assumes that too, so within the context of *their* question *I'm* not assuming anything.